# Can NativeProcess.isSupported and Updater.isSupported both be true in an AIR application?

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, air-native-extension

I'm trying to check user domain name in Windows, and need native process support.

In the application config xml (`xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.6"`) I have

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop desktop</supportedProfiles>
```

When I run the application with adl everything works, but when I trying to installing the application (*.air package), I get an error that native proccess is not supported. Interesting that when I install the compiled *.exe file, after installation I have native processes support.

But with *.exe installation I have `Updater.isSupported == false`, but, when I'm installing with *.air package I have `Updater.isSupported == true`.

Looks like when I'm installing *.exe I have profile=extendedDesktop, but when I'm using *.air installation package I have using profile=desktop.

But I need both. Is there any way to solve this problem?

compilation:

```
echo Creating air application
call g:\flex_sdk\bin\adt.bat -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore mykey.p12 -storepass simple -tsa none  news.air news-app.xml .
echo Compile exe
call g:\flex_sdk\bin\adt.bat -package -target native news.exe news.air
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible. [`ApplicationUpdater`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/air/update/ApplicationUpdater.html) provided by Adobe does not work with native-code applications.

(You can see the code if you'd like more information on why; it is available in your sdk directory under `\frameworks\projects\air\ApplicationUpdater\src`.)

However, it is possible to automatically update native-code packaged applications in a similar, though not completely identical, way. See this post on Adobe's website for more information: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/updating-air-apps-native-installer.html. I would provide the information here, but I am not the author of that article.